# Why when changing transition between two states in animator it's not changing it slow and smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It does change the states and play the animation but it's doing it at once there is no delay slow motion when changing between the states.

Grounded is > HumanoidIdle

And a transition from Grounded to Walk. This part is working fine the changing between the Grounded and Walk is slowly and smooth.

The Walk parameter is a bool type.

[image: Animator > Grounded to Walk]

The problem is the transition from the Walk to Use.
It's changing from Walk to Use at once immediately there is no delay/slow motion.

[image: Animator > Walk to Use]

This is the script I'm using to trigger the states:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class SpaceshipCutscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform[] npcs;
    public Transform console;
    public Camera FPSCamera;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Animator[] anim;
    public float rotationSpeed = 3f;

    private bool moveNpc = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (moveNpc)
        {
            // Soldier 2 rotating and looking at player
            Vector3 dir = player.position - npcs[0].position;
            dir.y = 0; // keep the direction strictly horizontal
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
            // slerp to the desired rotation over time
            npcs[0].rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npcs[0].rotation, rot, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            float dist = Vector3.Distance(npcs[1].position, console.position);
            if (dist < 4f)
            {
                anim[1].SetTrigger("Use");
            }

            Vector3 dirToComputer = console.transform.position - npcs[1].position;
            dirToComputer.y = 0;
            Quaternion rot1 = Quaternion.LookRotation(dirToComputer);
            npcs[1].rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npcs[1].rotation, rot1, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpaceshipCutscene")
        {
            FPSCamera.enabled = false;
            mainCamera.enabled = true;
            moveNpc = true;
            anim[0].SetBool("Aiming", true);
            anim[1].SetBool("Walk", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation claims that

> A transition from one motion to a completely different motion is usually fine if the transition is quick.

But transition from "Walk" to "Use" probably requires using [Blend Trees](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) to make it smooth.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeHvlEYpRbM) can be helpful.

Good luck!